# ASP.Net Core cross Project reference Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, build, self-hosting

I have to merge two self-hosting Asp.net Core Web projects.
I need them as one Service and with one Navigation. I would prefer not to “physically” merge them since they have some conflicts. 
I hoped I just could add Project2 as reference to Project1, change the startup.cs and appsettings.json a bit and it would somehow work. : )

At least the adding as Project reference gave me a Project2.Views.dll in my Project1 folder but I had no clue how to address any of my Project2 Pages now. 
First guess attempts like the following did not work:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Project2/pages/Index")
@await Html.PartialAsync("Project2")
…
```

After reading a bit into it, I found a promising guide for ASP .Net Core Embedded Resources.
https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2017/07/21/asp-net-core-mvc-common-components-view-across-applications/
Sadly, this guide is 3 Years old and only works with .net core 2.2

I am sure there must be an easy way for displaying Webpages from other Projects without hosting them separately and address them absolute.
A potential second Problem I have: My Project2 uses Pages and Project1 Views but I’m not sure if this takes impact on my first problem.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:**
I saw https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307467/how-to-create-an-asp-net-application-from-multiple-projects-for-team-d
but its a bit more work than i like and it does not exactly fir my requirments

**Edit Edit:**
i ended up merging them by hand  :/

Comment: Looking at the same issue. Anybody, or do we want things that is rocket science